# Auto complete PR via poweshell script Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a powershell script to automate a PR creation and completion after there's a commit on a specific branch.

I tested it on 2 test branches after giving **Project Collection Build Service (org name)**

**bypass policy** -Allow
[image]

**Contribute** - Allow

It works fine i.e. creates and completes the PR.

I'm trying to use the script on our **develop** branch with the same script and configuration.

What I see is that the PR is created with autocomplete mode BUT I still get that one of the members of our team needs to approve it AND a working item has to be connected.

I can't find where do I need to remove those restrictions.

**Update**

Just to clarify, I don't want to enable all users to push content to the **develop** branch but only to **Project Collection Build Service (org name)**

Comment: not only bypass, but "push to master" permission is what you need (the privilege under bypass policies)

Answer (score 1):

You can go the Pull requests UI page to check what was the build service account that created this Pull request. If the pull request was created in a build pipeline. It will show that the Pull request was created by account `ProjectName Build Service (OrganizationName)`. See below:

[image]

Then you probably need to give account `ProjectName Build Service (OrganizationName)` bypass policy -Allow permission too.

[image]

If you set the permission on the Repository level. You need to go to develop branch's permission page to make sure the allow permission is not overrode in the branch level.

Comment: I looked the the service name and it's identical to the service name on the branch itself which has bypass policies - Allow.

Comment: Were you using the system generated access token `$(system.accesstoken)`  for authorization or a PAT generated by yourself in your powershell script?

Comment: In my script, I'm using:
$head = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"  }

Answer (score 0):

Please check your branch policy (if you have any) as it is shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops)

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer @Krzysztof. I read the content of the link. Like I mentioned in my post, I already gave Project Collection Build Service (msazure) bypass policy = Allow so according to the wiki, it should work and bypass other polcy but it doesn't. If I'll disable the branch policy, it would mean all users would be able to push complete content into develop

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: Updated original question